# Prove that lim$_{n → \infty} \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt(sin \frac{x}{n} + x + 1) dx$ exists and evaluate it

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence

Prove that the following limits exist and evaluate them.

c) $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{\sin \frac{x}{n} + x + 1}\ \text dx$

I need to use the following theorem from analysis;

Suppose $f_n \to f$ uniformly on a closed interval [a,b]. If each $f_n$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then so is $f$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b}f_n(x) \text dx = \int_{a}^{b}[\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) ]\text dx $.

My attempt: Let $f_n = \sqrt{\sin \frac{x}{n} + x + 1}$. Recall |$\sin\frac{x}{n}| \leq 1$ for all x in [0,3].

First we try to find the $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n = f(x)$ so it we can for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|f_n(x) - f(x) | < \epsilon$
However, the limit does not exists when for  $f_n = \sqrt{\sin \frac{x}{n} + x + 1}$ because of sine.

Can someone please help me? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The limit is $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$, is not it ?

Comment: the limit does not exist, it diverges

Comment: See the answer below the $\sin$ vanish.

Comment: I believe your main problem is how to prove the uniform convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=\sqrt{\sin{\frac{x}{n}}+x+1}$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$. Then $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[0,3]$ (this requires proof but not too difficult) and then use your Uniform Convergence Theorem to get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^3\sqrt{\sin{\frac{x}{n}}+x+1}\,dx=\int_0^3\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\sin{\frac{x}{n}}+x+1}\,dx=\int_0^3\sqrt{x+1}\,dx
$$
which you finish off with a quick $u-$ substitution.

UPDATE: I just reread your post and I see the problem is the uniform convergence part of the proof. Recall that for sufficiently large $n$ we have $\sin\frac{x}{n}\approx\frac{x}{n}$.

UPDATE 2: Rather than an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof, another way we can demonstrate uniform convergence is if
$$
\sup_{x\in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0\,\,\text{ as }\,\,n\to\infty.
$$
So
$$
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x\in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)|&=\sup_{x\in [0,3]}\left\lvert\sqrt{\sin{\frac{x}{n}}+x+1}-\sqrt{x+1}\,\right\rvert\\
&=\sqrt{\sin{\frac{3}{n}}+3+1}-\sqrt{3+1}\to 0\,\,\text{ as }\,\,n\to\infty.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: So when writing the proof for the epsilon part we would have to show  $|\sqrt(sin \frac{x}{n} + x + 1) - \sqrt(x +1)| < \epsilon$?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: how could we simplify that expression, can we plug in values for x? in the end, that expression has to be less than or equal to an expression with only n.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that this could be the answer you expect; so, please forgive me if I am off-topic.

When $n$ is large, we can approximate $\sin(x)$ by its Taylor expansion built at $x=0$. The problem is that only the first term of the expansion can be used (otherwise we should bump on nasty elliptic integrals).

$$I_n=\int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{\sin (\frac{x}{n}) + x + 1}\, dx\approx \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{\frac{x}{n} + x + 1}\, dx=\frac{2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{n}+4}\, (4 n+3)-n\right)}{3 (n+1)}$$ the limit of which being $\frac{14}3$ which is, as expected, the value of $\int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{ x + 1}\, dx$.

Comparing with the results of numerical integration (given in parentheses), the match is quite correct as shown below for a few values on $n$.

$$I_{5}=4.92550\cdots (4.91865)$$
$$I_{10}=4.79798\cdots (4.79709)$$
$$I_{15}=4.75465\cdots (4.75438)$$
$$I_{20}=4.73282\cdots (4.73271)$$

A Taylor expansion of the approximation gives $$I_n \approx \frac{14}{3}+\frac{4}{3 n}-\frac{5}{24 n^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^3\right)$$ showing how the limit is reached.

Curve fitting the results of the numerical integration for the range $5\leq n\leq 100$ leads to $$I_n=\frac{14}{3}+\frac{1.34057}{n}-\frac{0.389332}{n^2}$$ which is extremely close.